# Complexity 0 Notation

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I am a bit confused on this question and would appreciate some guidance on it:

> An O(n2) function takes approx 1 second to run when N is 10000.
>
> How long will it take when N is 30000?

I was thinking that it would either be 1 second as well or 3 seconds since it is three times the size, but I am not sure if my logic is correct.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "n2"?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I think he means n^2, making the answer 9 seconds as A. says below. If that's correct Alex, I can edit your post to improve clarity if you'd like.

Comment: yes you are correct, its n^2 my mistake, I copied it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity):

> In computer science, the time complexity of an algorithm quantifies the amount of time taken by an algorithm to run as a function of the length of the string representing the input.

This way, if complexity is `O(n^2)` and input is `3` times greater, then time of work is `3^2 = 9` times greater. Time of work is `9` seconds.

Comment: thank you! the next question asks for when n is 5000, would the answer for this be 0.15 seconds?

Comment: my working is 1/2^2, as its half the input, which is 0.25, then i would divide 60 by 0.25 which would give me 15 milliseconds or 0.15 seconds?

Comment: @Alex - well, it's a different question but the answer is 0.25s not 0.15s. No need to multiply it by 60. There 1000 milliseconds in one second. Anyway, if it solved your problem you may accept the answer

Comment: @Alex - just click a tick to the left from an answer

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with the question.

First problem: time complexity does not, in general, measure time in seconds. For example, the time complexity of a sorting algorithm might refer to the number of comparisons (or swaps), and the time complexity of a hash table lookup might also refer to the number of comparisons performed. It's debatable whether the actual runtime is proportional to these measurements.

Second problem: the definition of big-O is this:

> f(n) = O(g(n)) if there's N and k such that n > N implies f(n) < k*g(n).

That's a problem because even if the runtime in this case is measured in seconds, applying the definition to O(n^2) says only that for large enough n that the function is bounded above by some multiple of n^2.

So there's no guarantee that 10000 and 30000 are big enough to qualify for "big enough", and even if they were, you can't begin to estimate k from a single data point. And even with that estimate, you only get an upper bound.

What the question probably meant to ask was this:

> Suppose that a function runs in time approximately proportional to n^2. It takes 1 second when n=10000. Approximately long does it take when n=30000?

Then, one can solve the equations:

```
1 sec ~= k * 10000^2
answer ~= k * 30000^2
        = 3^2 * k * 10000^2
        ~= 3^2 * 1 sec
        = 9 sec
```

Comment: hi thanks for your concerns, its a sample college exam for me, i dont get to decide the question, i am just looking for help on how to solve it